# Google Play services and Google Games

Tags: android, google-play-services

I would like to ask what are Google Games good for from the developer point of view. If I am connecting viac `GoogleApiClient` like:

```
googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
```

Am I connecting to Google Play services or Google Games. And if I am connecting to Google Games I don't need to have google play services installed? Because it eats a lot of space on older devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `GoogleApiClient` is used as main entry point for Google Play Services integration ([as in google documentation explained](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient))

**Google Play Services**

The role of these services is to connect your app with google play store to check updates . Play Services library is used to in android app project to have classes which able us to use google maps and other google+ API's . more info [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview)

**Google Play Game Services**

As quoted on wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play_Services#Google_Play_Game_Services) `Google Play Game Services can be used by application developers to allow a more competitive and social experience through the use of leaderboards, both public and between friends, achievements and multiplayer sessions. Saved Games API is available to quickly sync game saves on Google's cloud infrastructure as well.`

We can say that play services are used to save score of games and can have score boards of other players played your game. This gives a more rich game experience.

Comment: Fair enough, so withou google play services i cant acces leaderboards and achievments

Comment: No, for leaderboards and achievements  you need to implement `Google Play Games Services`